# Android HttpURLConnection POST getInputStream response data not returns array content

Tags: android, post, httpurlconnection

I am trying to get data after performing "POST" request with getInputStream(). I am getting the data. But with "Postman" I am seeing that part of the data not received.

getting following on android :
**{"data":{"companies":[],"trends":[],"users":[]},"meta":{"total_companies":1000,"total_trends":5,"total_users":11}}**

but "postman" returns following:
**{"data":{"companies":[{"name":"Hostess","description":null},{"name":"Tesco","description":null},{"name":"Whitestrips (Crest)","description":null}],"trends":[],"users":[{"id":10,"first_name":"Test","last_name":"test","password":"","suffix":null,"gender":"U","email":"test@test.com","email_work":null,"company":null,"facebook":null,"twitter":null,"birth_date":"2016-06-14","country":null,"language":null,"is_admin":0,"is_active":1,"personality":null,"degree_id":null,"registration_date":{"date":"2016-12-07 14:57:26.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"UTC"},"ideas_count":0,"followers_count":1,"follows_count":0,"is_following":false,"follows_trends_count":0,"suggested_trends_count":0}]},"meta":{"total_companies":1000,"total_trends":5,"total_users":11}}**

So seems that companies and users array data not received.
I am doing following for POST request:

```
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(apiUrl);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            String userAuth = USERNAME + ":" + PASSWORD;
            String basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(Base64.encode(userAuth.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP));
            Log.d("SerachApi", "User Auth is: " + basicAuth);
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", basicAuth);
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("keyword", searchFor));
            OutputStream os = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(getQuery(params));
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();


            urlConnection.connect();

            // Get response code
            int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
            Log.d("SerachApi", "Response Code is: " + responseCode);

            // Read the input stream into a String
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    inputStream));
            List<String> response = new ArrayList<String>();

            String line = "";
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                response.add(line);
                Log.d ("aaaaa", line);
            }
            bufferedReader.close();

        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The code is correct, just I was putting wrong value for keyword.

Answer (score 0):

The code is correct, just I was putting wrong value for keyword.